# Symbols showing on blue background in Debian with oh-my-fish on WSL

Tags: debian, fish, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using fish-shell on Debian with oh-my-fish installed. When I run the shell, it shows the prompt not on the black bckground, but on the light blue instead. 
This is running in Windows Terminal with Campbell theme and Consolas font (and as for oh-my-fish, the default theme).

[image]

On the plain WSL, in fact, this is even worse. Instead of showing the cross, it shows the question mark.

[image]

Is this supposed to be like so or is this some kind of an error? If this is an error, please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party terminal emulator in Windows side (like ConEmu, Cmder etc.) or its just Command Prompt (cmd)?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Ah, yes, I use the Windows Terminal one.